# how to execute callback sequentially in Angular

Tags: angular, asynchronous, observable

How to enforce Angular to wait until fetching data is completeley finished before resuming the execution in ngOnInit:

```
fetchdata() {
    console.log('2')
   
   this.http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").subscribe(
     (data) => {
         console.log('3')
         return data
    })
}

ngOnInit() {
    console.log('1')
    this.httpdata = this.fetchdata()
    console.log('4')
}
```

in the example above, the order of `console.log` is 1, 2, 4, 3

I know that get function of httpclient is asynchron, but how can I make my function fetchdata asynchron too?

just declaring the function as async keeps the console.log in same order, and throws execution time error too:

```
async fetchdata() {
    console.log('2')
    this.http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").subscribe(
     (data) => {
        console.log('3')
        return data
    })
}
```

How can I declare my function fetchdata as observable?

Comment: even with the deprecated toPromise(), I can't correct the order of logs as wanted

  async fetchdata(){
    console.log('2')
    const res = await this.http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").toPromise()
    console.log('3')
    return res
}

Comment: Have you tried with `this.httpdata = await this.fetchdata()`?

Comment: @Misha Mashina, this brings an error:
'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is by subscribing to the method.

```
ngOnInit() {
   console.log('1')
   this.fetchdata().subscribe({
      next: (data: string) => { 

        this.httpdata = data;
        console.log('4')},

      error: (error) => { }
   });
}
```

Note: this is for an API call scenario where you are expecting an ok from the server or an error.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but shouldnt my fetchdata function be declared as observable before? Ohterwise I can't subscribe to it.

Comment: under my understanding, it is a good practice to have an angular service to make the API calls, when I subscribe to a method, I prepare it like this:

public nameOfTheMethod(data1: string, data2: string): Observable<string>.

you can find more information about this in the official documentation

https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: Antonia Redondo Cnteno, it has worked just after declaring my function to have output of Observable.

  public fetchdata():Observable<any> {
    console.log('2')
    this.httpdata = this.http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
    console.log('3')
   return this.httpdata
}

Comment: Is it also possible to add a further step to process data after fetching and before ngOnInit.

Something like this:
<pre>
public fetchdata() {   
  console.log('3')
 return this.http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
}
public processData():Observable<any>{
  console.log('2')
  this.fetchdata().subscribe((data)=>{
    console.log('4')
    return data   
  });   
}
ngOnInit() {
  console.log('1')
    this.processData().subscribe ((data)=>{
      console.log('5')
   this.httpdata=data
  console.log('6')
 })
}
</pre>

Answer (score 0):

Please use pipes and `map` operator to perform additional operations, then you can subscribe at the end to make the actions act sequentially!

```
fetchdata() {
    console.log('2')
   
    return this.http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
}

ngOnInit() {
    console.log('1')
    this.fetchdata().subscribe((data) => {
        this.httpdata = data;
        console.log('4')
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks, it workd, but could you please explain why we used 2X return in fetchdata? At the first moment I thought this will bring error.

Comment: @Troy I assumed you are doing something in `console.log('3')` part, if not you can remove the pipe and map entirely!

Comment: how should it look like after removing pipe and map?